# how can i chain boolean logic statements with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean

How would i write
(A OR B) AND B

in a controller?

Now i have this (a OR b)

@articles = Article.where ("author = ? OR title = ?"),  params[:author],params[:title])

Or is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result? (scopes??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely the sort of problem that I wrote MetaWhere (http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere) to solve.

With MetaWhere, that query would be writen something like this:

```
@articles = Article.where(:author.eq % params[:author] | :title.eq % params[:title])
```

or this:

```
@articles = Article.where({:author => params[:author]} | {:title => params[:title]})
```